# How to create multiple keys for the same object in Amazon S3 OR CLOUDFRONT?

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-web-services

I am syndicating out my multi-media content (mp4 and images) to  several clients. So I create one S3 object for every mp4 say "my_content_that_pays_my_bills.mp4" and let the client access the S3 URL for  the objects and embed it wherever they want.

What I want is for client A to access this MP4 as "A_my_content_that_pays_my_bills.mp4"

and  Client B to access this as "B_my_content_that_pays_my_bills.mp4" and so on.

I want to bill the clients by usage: so I could process access  logs and count access to "B_my_content_that_pays_my_bills.mp4" and bill client B for usage.

I know that S3 allows only one key per object. So how do I get around this ?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know that you can alias file names in the way you'd like.  Here are a couple of hacks I can think of for public files embedded freely by a customer:

1) Create one Cloudfront distribution per client, each pointing at the same bucket.  Each AWS account can have 100 distributions, so you could support only that many clients.  Or,

2) Duplicate the files, using the the client-specific names that you'd like.  This is simpler but your file storage costs scale with your clients (which may or may not be significant).